# Use spacy-lookup with lemmatized sentence?

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I have input sentences that contain custom multi-word entities that I need to match, so for this purpose I'm using the excellent [spacy-lookup](https://github.com/mpuig/spacy-lookup) library. However, it has one flaw; it can't recognize plural words in the sentence that it has as entities. For example, if I declare `banana` as an entity, and have `short blue bananas` as a sentence, it won't recognise that `bananas` is an entity. My current 'fix' for this is to do something like this:

```
# Start by lowering inputLine (just in case) and removing any whitespace trailing/leading.
doc = nlp(inputLine.lower().strip())
# Lemmatize the words so things like bananas => banana.
words = list(map(lambda token: token.lemma_, doc))
lemmatized = ' '.join(words)
```

Basically running nlp over the original sentence and stringing the lemmas together to create a new sentence. However, this would require me to run nlp on the lemmatized sentence to extract the entities with spacy-lookup, and that just feels... wrong. Am I missing something in the pipeline that would enable the spacy-lookup to check lemmas instead of original words, and therefore have to call nlp only once?

Comment: what does the member variable `lemma_` contain?

Comment: It contains `banana`, which is as I need it to be.

Answer (score 2):

You're not missing any obvious solutions to have spacy-lookup look at lemmas. spacy-lookup says directly in the README (towards the end of the usage section): "`spacy-lookup` only cares about the token text"

You would have to change spacy-lookup to get it to do what you want, around [here](https://github.com/mpuig/spacy-lookup/blob/a0ecae9ae225c29bc0e99bd7d056ca7d65860396/spacy_lookup/__init__.py#L43):

```
matches = self.keyword_processor.extract_keywords(doc.text, span_info=True)
```

You could potentially change `doc.text` to something else here (e.g., `' '.join([token.lemma_ for token in doc])`), but then you have problems because spacy-lookup relies on character offsets in the document text to process the entity spans, so you'd have to rework the entity span detection/merging to have it use token offsets instead of character offsets to align the entities with the original document text. (It would be doable, but a bit of a hassle.)

If all you need is entity lookup, you could use spacy (or NLTK or something else) to generate the lemmas and then flashtext on its own to find entities, skipping spacy-lookup entirely. If you don't need any further spacy analysis, then this would be the easiest option.

Other notes:

- spacy-lookup seems to have an option for case-insensitive searching (through an option passed through to flashtext)
- if you want to use spacy and if spacy's lemmatization is good enough for what you need (check carefully!), there's no need to use NLTK instead; you could create a faster pipeline that disables the components that you don't need:

  ```
  nlp = spacy.load('en', disable=['tagger', 'parser', 'ner'])
  ```

Comment: I'm in fact doing your suggested solution right now, where I use `flashtext` on a `' '.join(lemmas)` reconstructed sentence. However my problem is that I need to find any negators or other adjectives for the keywords, e.g. if the input was `not soft bananas`, `soft` would have a child whose dependency would be `neg` and I'd know that I'd need to negate `soft`. Therefore whenever I find a keyword, I need to find its associated token in the `nlp` run so I can check for that, which in turn requires entities, so multi-word keywords (like, I dunno `fancy banana`) are recognized.

Comment: If you don't want to modify spacy-lookup, then I would suggest using something other than flashtext to find the keywords. If you're parsing documents with spacy, then you might be able to deal with a slightly slower / more flexible keyword detection method that looks at tokens and lemmas?

Comment: What other options are there other than flashtext? I'm ok with slightly slower methods, since I want to get the dependency/negation information anyway.

Comment: Maybe take a look at spacy's Matcher and PhraseMatcher? I suspect at least one of them can do what you want. (https://spacy.io/api/matcher / https://spacy.io/api/phrasematcher ) I haven't tried it, but it looks like there's a demo here: https://explosion.ai/demos/matcher

Comment: The matcher (at least from the demo) doesn't work with multi-word keywords, so I tried the phrase matcher. I copied the example code from the last example on the API page and pasted it into one of the editable code examples in https://spacy.io/usage/spacy-101. It looks like it still doesn't work on lemmas, since it didn't match the `healthcare reforms` in the test sentence, but it did when I changed it to `healthcare reform`.

Comment: This is really turning into a separate question, but I think you can match multiple tokens in a sequence with Matcher based on lemmas. Look at the example in the demo with `LEMMA: match` followed by `LEMMA: be`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use, `WordNet lemmatizer` from the `NLTK` module like so:

```
>>> import nltk
>>> from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
>>>
>>> wordnet_lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
>>> wordnet_lemmatizer.lemmatize("bananas")
banana
```

So, according to your example, you can do something like this:

```
sentence = "short blue bananas"
for word in sentence.split(" "):
    word = word.lower()
    print(wordnet_lemmatizer.lemmatize(word))
```

And it would print `short blue banana`

If you don't know how to use `nltk`.. follow this:

1. Install NLTK module by running `pip install nltk`
2. open the terminal and type the following to download popular packages in NLTK.

```
$ python
Python 3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Apr 29 2018, 16:14:56) 
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import nltk
>>> nltk.download('popular')
>>> nltk.download('wordnet')
```

Comment: How do you suggest I use that in conjunction with spacy-lookup? I tested it with actual sentences (like my `short blue bananas` example), and it failed to lemmatize 'bananas' properly.

Comment: You need to use it *word by word*